# reference needed for Gamma function

Tags: reference-request, inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

Please help me to find a reference (book) for the following upper bound of Gamma function

For $x \geq 1$
$$
\Gamma(x)\leq x^{x-1}.
$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be a book? [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-11/S0002-9939-97-04152-X/) is the original paper (Anderson and Qiu 1997).

Comment: Was this result first found really as late as 1997?